# How to access a wsdl URL in SoapUI, which recquires username/password?

Tags: wsdl, soapui

How to access a wsdl URL in `SOAPUI`, which recquires username/password ?

`http://localhost:8080/ws/hello1?wsdl`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug with retrieving password protected WSDLs in SoapUI 4.6.4. The bug is fixed 5.0.0 and can be downloaded from http://www.soapui.org/

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Joel Jonsson, Could you please let me know how to access the protected WSDL ?

Comment: With SoapUI 4.6.4-m (maintenance version) or later you open the New SOAP Project as normal. Enter the URL to the WSDL and press OK. Now you _should_ get a dialog asking for username and password. Even if you enter your credentials correctly you might get the dialog a couple of times more (once per resource it fetches).

Comment: Unfortunately, the bug is still not fixed in 5.0.0. I've had to download the Soap UI Pro v5.1.2 (with a trial licence) to get password protected WSDLs to work.

Comment: Works fine (i.e. with basic auth) in 5.2.1 open source version

Comment: 5.6.0 and the bug's still here (open source version).

Answer (score 2):

When you create new project using wsdl or add a wsdl in existing project for a secure webservice, it asks for user id and password several times the simple solution is adding **myuser:mypassword@**

https://myuser:mypassword@mywebservice:9052/sdv/ErpHub/1.0?wsdl

Comment: In case your username/password has an **@** you must use the url encoded replacement for it which is **%40**. (probably other url encodable character should be encoded too)

Comment: Did not work with 5.7.0, but did work on browser.