# GuideWire Webservice

Tags: guidewire

**How to fetch wsdl with user name password into Guidewire?**

*I tried to add wsdl end pointn in Webservice collection in Guidwire studio, but it not downloaded into my project it due to, it has password credential.*  
 *See below image, after created wsc, Add resource is accepting only http url not local file path* 
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690574/how-to-access-a-wsdl-url-in-soapui-which-recquires-username-password

Comment: @Umanath Actually resource URL will take only http path and not any other thing. Can you attach a screenshot you are getting while fetching the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WSDL trought the browser and load in WSC (Web service collection) as local file.

Comment: I tried, it not possible to load local file (wsdl file, even i have)

Comment: Do you tried something like that in Resource URL?
file:///D:/MyFolder/MyFile.wsdl

Answer (score -1):

When you add the WSDL in Resource URL, your .wsc file actually connects to the WSDL file location (can be a external system or a file location). For this your local machine should have the access to download the WSDL file and add the WSDL file to your webservice collection (.wsc) folder.
To check this, try to open the WSDL file through the browser. if you are able to open the WSDL file then you should not get any issues in adding the WSDL in Resource URL field.
If you can not open the WSDL file in browser, then your machine is not capable of accessing the WSDl file.